# Legends of LOESS plotted line

Tags: python, altair

Following example dataset to illustrate question regarding formatting

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.cars()

x = alt.Chart(source).mark_circle(size=60).encode(
    x='Horsepower',
    y='Miles_per_Gallon',
    color='Origin',
    )

x + x.transform_loess('Horsepower', 'Miles_per_Gallon').mark_line()
```

[image]

1. How to change the name of the "undefined" LOESS plotted line in the colour legend on the right;
2. Is there a way to just remove the legend for the LOESS plotted line, while keeping "Europe, Japan and USA";

I can not seem to find for `mark_line()` an appropriate "mark property" flag and I cannot pass `legend=None`

PS: As this chart needs to be combined with `Alt.vconcat/hconcat`, it needs to happen at the base level I think;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to know is that legends come from encodings: if you don't want a field to appear in a color legend, don't give it a color encoding. If you do want it to appear, give it a color encoding that reflects what you want to be in the legend

When you write something like `x.transform_loess(...)` the resulting chart inherits all encodings defined in `x`. The LOESS transform produces a new dataset that does not contain anything but the target variables, and so the `color='Origin'` encoding points to an undefined column.

If you want that undefined column to not appear in the legend, then avoid a color encoding for the transformed chart:

```python
x = alt.Chart(source).mark_circle(size=60).encode(
    x='Horsepower',
    y='Miles_per_Gallon',
)

x.encode(color='Origin') + x.transform_loess('Horsepower', 'Miles_per_Gallon').mark_line()
```

[image]

On the other hand, if you want the legend to say something else, you'll need a column to use for the color encoding, which you can create using a calculate transform:

```python
x = alt.Chart(source).mark_circle(size=60).encode(
    x='Horsepower',
    y='Miles_per_Gallon',
    color='Origin'
)

x + x.transform_loess(
        'Horsepower', 'Miles_per_Gallon'
    ).transform_calculate(
        Origin='" LOESS"'
    ).mark_line()
```

[image]